# pymysql (1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Мой первый код в данной библиотеке. Искал решение часа 3, не нашел, были решения только на других языках. Помогите пожалуйста. Если понадобится вот источник кода: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LS42t1VMwuM&t=372s&ab_channel=PythonToday

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
from config import host,user,password,db_name

try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
                             host='localhost',
                             port=3306,
                             user='user',
                             password='password',
                             database='db',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    print('Connected...')
    print('-' * 20)

    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            create_table_query = 'CREATE TABLE `users`(id int AUTO_INCREMENT), name varchar(32), password varchar(32), email varchar(32), PRIMARY KEY(id))'
            cursor.execute(create_table_query)
            print('table created')
    finally:
        connection.close()


except Exception as ex:
    print('Connection refused...', ex)
```

Comment: При чём тут код-то, если у вас пароль неправильный

Comment: Просто первый запуск MySQL, вот не знаю какой может быть пароль если по идее я сам его задаю. В общем я запутался

Comment: Ну питон тут уже ни при чём, читайте документацию по установке mysql или типа того

Comment: Видео, на которое вы ссылаетесь, похоже, в принципе не рассматривает установку и настройку mysql и подразумевает, что вы сами всё заранее установили и настроили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я просто поменял `user='root'` и `password=''`, мне для локальной системы этого хватает